# Move title between sort by and number of items

Tags: magento2.3, xml

I need my title of the category page to be placed between the number of items and the sort by option. What should I do?

[image: The location where the title has to be]

Which container has to be moved to which destination?

Comment: Provide more information about your question

Comment: i first moved the title from         <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="category.products"/>
 but I couldn't place the title between the sortby option and the number of items. @AshishRanade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly remove title block from your custom frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
```

Then this is the file from where you can inject title block
**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml** make sure to override the file.

Title block is called something like

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.title" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml"/>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have set using the "set template" like "        <?php include ($block->setTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml')) ?>
" but I couldn't get the output. Can you please say how to set the template in it? @YashPatadia

Comment: I got the answer @YashPatadia

Comment: great :) enjoy coding..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the title above content please follow the below steps.

> In the folder vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/ is
>   the file catalog_category_view.xml.

Copy this file to your own theme folder or module folder (if you don't know how to create a theme or a module take a look in the dev docs from Magento).

Add the following line at the end of that file before the closing body tag

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="category.products"/>
```

Comment: I tired it but it didn't work out @YoYoRoshan

Comment: @Haerriz Can you please Flush the cache: php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Ya I did that. Can you please read my comment on the question. I did the same thing already @YoYoRoshan

Comment: @Haerriz can you once try answer posted by #YashPatadia